# object reference not set to an instance of an object while registering bot

Tags: botframework

I created a simple Bot and its working fine in bot emulator.

I published this Bot into Microsoft azure and trying to registering my Bot with the Microsoft Bot Framework.

I am getting the following error.

object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Can you try in a different browser? I believe it's transient error of the portal

Answer (score 0):

According to this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1012 This error can occur if you do not put a url in the terms of use form field.